# Check if page accepts messages

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I know that I can use a link to www.facebook.com/messages/[user_id]?msg_prefill=XXX to let users send a message to a facebook page (user_id/page_id). But in advance I need to know how to check if the fanpage accepts messages (this can be disabled by admins). If no messages will be accepted I would have to hide the link.

Comment: I don’t see any way of getting that info from the API. It only tells you if the current user can make posts on a page wall, but nothing about messages.